# How to find substrings in a string that end when they reach a character pattern (Python)

Tags: python

I have one long string which is dozens of urls.  Is there a non-regex way to turn this into a list of urls, starting with the pattern `'http'` and ending each substring when `'http'` is found a second time?

`http://www.annuncibdsm.in/?view=selectcity&targetview=posthttp://www.bakecaincontri.in/?view=selectcity&targetview=posthttp://www.incontrixxx.in/?view=selectcity&targetview=posthttp://www.annuncixadulti.com/?view=selectcity&targetview=posthttp://dubizzle.us/?view=selectcity&targetview=posthttp://xincontri.com/index.php?view=selectcityhttp://www.18plusservices.com/mobile/?view=selectcity&targetview=post&cityid=0&lang=enhttp://www.mercatoneannunci.net/?view=selectcity&targetview=post&catid=46&cityid=-18&lang=it</a>http://www.annonce-be.com/?view=selectcity&targetview=post&cityid=-1&lang=fr`

It's one long string without breaks.

Comment: Please post the string of urls example. And why don't you want a regex?

Comment: I've tried using regex already and wanted to see if there was a way to do this similar to string.find('substring').. Except for this it's going to be a varying substring each time so can't be used

Comment: Why don't you use urls_str = original_string.split('http') and iterate then?

Comment: That works well except for deleting all `'http'`'s and I need the end result to be a list of `http://...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this:

```
" http".join(url.split("http")).split()
```

---

```
>>> url = "http://www.annuncibdsm.in/?view=selectcity&targetview=posthttp://www.bakecaincontri.in/?view=selectcity&targetview=posthttp://www.incontrixxx.in/?view=selectcity&targetview=posthttp://www.annuncixadulti.com/?view=selectcity&targetview=posthttp://dubizzle.us/?view=selectcity&targetview=posthttp://xincontri.com/index.php?view=selectcityhttp://www.18plusservices.com/mobile/?view=selectcity&targetview=post&cityid=0&lang=enhttp://www.mercatoneannunci.net/?view=selectcity&targetview=post&catid=46&cityid=-18&lang=it</a>http://www.annonce-be.com/?view=selectcity&targetview=post&cityid=-1&lang=fr"
>>> " http".join(url.split("http")).split()
['http://www.annuncibdsm.in/?view=selectcity&targetview=post', 'http://www.bakecaincontri.in/?view=selectcity&targetview=post', 'http://www.incontrixxx.in/?view=selectcity&targetview=post', 'http://www.annuncixadulti.com/?view=selectcity&targetview=post', 'http://dubizzle.us/?view=selectcity&targetview=post', 'http://xincontri.com/index.php?view=selectcity', 'http://www.18plusservices.com/mobile/?view=selectcity&targetview=post&cityid=0&lang=en', 'http://www.mercatoneannunci.net/?view=selectcity&targetview=post&catid=46&cityid=-18&lang=it</a>', 'http://www.annonce-be.com/?view=selectcity&targetview=post&cityid=-1&lang=fr']
>>>
```

---

Essentially this just adds a space before every `"http"` then splits by `" "`.

Comment: Glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Pythonic way to do it without using the re submodule:

```
str = "http://www.annuncibdsm.in/?view=selectcity&targetview=posthttp://www.bakecaincontri.in/?view=selectcity&targetview=posthttp://www.incontrixxx.in/?view=selectcity&targetview=posthttp://www.annuncixadulti.com/?view=selectcity&targetview=posthttp://dubizzle.us/?view=selectcity&targetview=posthttp://xincontri.com/index.php?view=selectcityhttp://www.18plusservices.com/mobile/?view=selectcity&targetview=post&cityid=0&lang=enhttp://www.mercatoneannunci.net/?view=selectcity&targetview=post&catid=46&cityid=-18&lang=it</a>http://www.annonce-be.com/?view=selectcity&targetview=post&cityid=-1&lang=fr"

list_of_urls =  ["http"+url for url in str.split("http") if url != ""]
```

[DEMO](https://repl.it/C8Kv/1)